# Snort rule for syn flood attacks - Limiting number of alerts

Tags: ids, denial-of-service, detection, snort, intrusion

So I have a snort rule that detects syn flood attacks that looks like this:

```
alert tcp any any -> $HOME_NET 80 (msg:”SYN Flood - SSH"; flags:S;
flow: stateless; detection_filter: track by_dst, count 40, seconds 10;
GID:1; sid:10000002; rev:001; classtype:attempted-dos;)
```

The problem is, when I trigger it using tcpreplay on vm2 (With a Ddos.pcapng file):

```
sudo tcpreplay -i interface /home/Practicak/DDoS.pcapng
```

When listening on my VM1, I get a lot of alerts when listening with the snort rule active. E.G. 100s of Syn Flood Detected alerts.

How can I limit this so that I only get few / 1 alert for each Syn Flood that is initiated? I.E. using the TCPReplay with the pcap file.. & is this good practice to display less alerts?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a siem or a syslog server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use thresholds (that were replaced with event_filters) to do this:

**/etc/snort/threshold.conf**

```
event_filter gen_id 1, sig_id 10000002, type limit, track by_src, count 1, seconds 3600
```

This will generate max. 1 alert per 1 hour for your rule